# Find string numbers for input

Tags: mathematics, steganography

There are 5 digit numbers for the door. Now I am going to find the input numbers to open and close the door. Therefore, it has two sets of numbers.

[image]

The answer is 2, 9, 4 to lock the door and 3,6,7 to unlock the door.

**Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question needs a lot of help, as the way it's written is rather incomprehensible.  I believe you're looking for distinct 5 digit sequences that will unlock and lock the door, respectively.

To unlock:

> Two strings will work, according to the provided state diagram.
>  `25594` and `31694`.
>
>  (It should also be noted that `255594`, `2555594`, and so on for any number of **5**s will work.  Including zero: `294` also works.  Similarly, `311694`, `3111694`, etc. for any number of **1**s, including zero. However, none of these other choices are five digits, which while not strictly required by the state diagram was nonetheless specified, I think, by the problem.)

To lock:

> `31167` is the only sequence that works here.
>
>  (As before, sequences of different length than 5 also are accepted by the state diagram: `311167`, `3111167`, etc., for any number of **1**s including zero.)

You've tagged this [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) and [steganography](/questions/tagged/steganography).  Unless there is far more to this question than the surface reading suggests, neither tag fits.

Comment: I think if the number is a wrong number (Which number is no in the graph) Example 3,8,6,0,4. The result will still go to unlock?

Comment: 38604 will not unlock - best case is it would be stuck in S4. 38694 however, *might*, but I doubt it. The fact that some digits explicitly loop back to the same state mean those digits for sure are accepted without changing state; other digits not thus shown probably cannot be assumed to be ignored with no state change. I would believe rather that they cause the input to be flagged as invalid. But this cannot be answered from the state diagram so we cannot know for sure.

Comment: Ok got it.How about if I draw a new diagram based on this Figure 2 diagram and use the new number "11119" to unlock the door.Is it possible?